# Is consuming glucose during workouts detrimental to weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, carbohydrate

I have recently started working out for an hour and a half every day. I drink about 1L of glucose-water during the entire process. Recently, someone commented that if I am aiming at losing weight, I should avoid glucose. Is that correct? I weigh about 93 kg and my ideal weight should be around 78 kg. I have been drinking glucose because I read about [the benefits of post workout carbohydrates](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/the-benefits-of-post-workout-carbohydrates.html) which advocated glucose over other forms.

p.s.: [This](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15507/is-it-ok-to-drink-glucose-water-during-workout) is a similar question. My question is more directly concerned with effects of glucose on losing weight.

Comment: If the question is solely a nutrition one, than it doesn't fit for this site. Sorry about that.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: It's asking how nutritional details relate to weight loss, though. That's kinda fitness-related.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla: I see now that we do allow general non-food weight loss questions. And I did miss where he indicated that this is in the context of working out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, If you're trying to lose weight, you should avoid high amounts of glucose.**

The link you provided lists the benefits of glucose, one of which is refueling muscle glycogen, which provides energy for your muscles. If you're not drinking glucose-water but plain water, that energy still has to come from somewhere, which would be (very simplified) from body fat. Since you're providing the energy with glucose water, your body doesn't need to use its fat reserves, so you won't lose that weight. Note that energy from body fat is not provided as easily, though, so you might not be performing as well if you ditch the glucose-water.

If you want to calculate this through, 1g of glucose can provide your body with 4kcal, so depending on how much glucose you put into your water (say 30g), the more calories you consume (30g -> 120kcal). If you still want to lose weight, those calories should go into your calculation (read: you eat less/exercise more) or they'll slow you down.